# angular select option not selected even there is default value set

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I already have existing value of the model I atteched with that particular select box, and I have different source list to render options, in that case I could not get select box to be selected with default value initially.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.new_object.name"><br/>
  <select name="test" id="test" ng-model="vm.new_object.provider_id">
    <option ng-repeat="opt in vm.list" value="{{opt.id}}" ng-selected="vm.new_object.provider_id == opt.id">
      {{opt.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {

vm = this;


vm.list = [{
  "id":1
  ,"name":"sdfgg"
  ,"website":"dfgdg"
  ,"is_active":"1"
  ,"is_deleted":"1"
}, {
  "id":2
  ,"name":"sfd"
  ,"website":"sdfsdf"
  ,"is_active":"1"
  ,"is_deleted":"0"
}, {
  "id":3
  ,"name":"sfs"
  ,"website":"dfsdfs"
  ,"is_active":"0"
  ,"is_deleted":"0"
}];

vm.new_object = {
  "name": "some thing"
  ,"provider_id": 2
}

})
```

[Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/HIqeWMDueHfG3MR3iUWq?p=preview)
this is demo plnkr link for the same issue.

Please haelp me out if have any idea arround it.

Comment: This question is asked every other day. Read the documentation. Use ng-options. https://plnkr.co/edit/r8O0yKnozC8g5IKgmsnV?p=preview

Comment: I gone through all the related questions asked, still not resolved my problem that's why I asked again with my use case

Comment: Thanks, this one works in edit option, but I am using the same thing in new option where I need 
<option value="" selected="selected">--please select--</option>
this kind of option at top if I don't found the value then this should be there, any idea?

Comment: Just add this unique empty option as a child of the select.

Comment: Okay, superb, thanks man @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

avoid using ng-repeat in selects. The proper usage is ng-options

```
<select name="test" id="test" ng-model="vm.new_object.provider_id"
         ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in vm.list">
</select>
```

Here is your updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CSyktyN5m4hnszjP6Mkt?p=preview)

Comment: I used ng repeat because I want  <option value="" selected="selected">--please select--</option>  this option while there is no already defined value

Comment: one more thing, I also need to filter using is_active flag